# Provide Url during debugging in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, debugging, node-inspector, node-debugger

I am using visual studio and node.js for program .I want to pass an URL and some data ate the time of debugging in nodejs. SO please tell me how to give that data.

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to pass an URL and some data, you need to define some variables to accept these value.

Then add breakpoint on one of the variable and start debugging your program. When the breakpoint hit, right-click it to choose **Add Watch** option. The variable will be listed in Watch window with it value.

Now you can set the value for the variable in the Watch window in Value column. When you press F10/F11 step to next, the variable will use the value that you set in the Watch Window in next line of code, which can implement your requirement pass data when debugging.
[image]